# Use Android-Studio on 32 bit Ubuntu

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, 32bit-64bit

I need to use Android-Studio on my 32 bit machine. I have Ubuntu installed, but I keep having issues even for execute "Hello world" on my phone. This is what I did:

- I changed default JDK location with my JDK location
- in the gradle file of the app I changed buildToolVersion from 25 to 23.0.1
- in the gradle file of my app i changed classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1' to classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'
- I put compileSdk, targetSdkVersion and minSdkVersion to 23 in the gradle file
- I changed compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+' with compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.+'

now I am having this problem:

```
Error:(11) No resource identifier found for attribute 'roundIcon' in package 'android'
```

and if I try to remove the roundIcon attribute from the manifest, it appears again, so I think the manifest is generated by something else which put the attribute roundIcon, which is not supported on API 23. Someone, please help me coding Android on 32-bit machine
This is my Manifest under the tag Application:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name="com.example.root.gbu.MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Did you change the `roundIcon` resource settings in `main_activity.xml`(or whatever the activity name is)?

Comment: In the file main-activity.xml there is no attribute roundIcon. it is in AndroidManifest.xml and, even if i change it, the attribute roundIcon appears again

Comment: Remove it from the manifest as suggested in one of the answers, then run `clean project` then run `build`

Comment: I remove it, I save, but when i click "clean project", gradle sync starts and "roundIcon" appears again. I am new in Android-Studio, so maybe i'm missing something obviously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i noticed that i was modifying the wrong manifest file, the correct path was app->manifest->AndroidManifest.xml. The one i was modifying was auto-generated

Answer (score 0):

In your `build.gradle` file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 25
    }
}
```

`roundIcon` attribute requires SDK 25. You need to set that SDK in your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: I can't: the latest buildToolsVersion supported by Ubuntu 32 bit is "23.0.1"